# Alternative for adder out of NAND-gates

Tags: adder, nand

Recently I was experimenting with the NAND-gate representation of an adder circuit and tried to implemenent it without crossing wires. So I got this:
[image: Flat half adder]

The carry is negated, but when chaining two of those together to a full adder, the negated carries can be combined with a NAND gate to give a normal carry. My questions are now: Does this design have any advantages or disadvantages compared to other ones (e.g. the one Wikipedia shows https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)) and is it used anywhere (I searched, but couldn't find it)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the rest of the circuit you're making. The max length of the signal path still goes through 3 chips, so the speed won't be significantly different to the standard one, but if you  had a circuit where you wanted a carry signal that was already inverted then it would be handy.